# Setting up multiple authentication methods for some requests only with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ssl-certificate

I am quite new to the world of Java Spring Boot and I am a bit confused on one of the projects I'm working on. This project requires the use of two authentication methods, and I need to use x509 for some requests only.

Basically, the application right now uses authentication using tokens, but let's say I am using basic authentication to simplify the process.
So I set up a basic test app, that uses basic authentication. I have a simple controller that has two methods.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
private String test() {
    return "we use basic auth only";
}

@GetMapping("/certiTest")
private String testCert() {
    return "we use certificate auth on this method";
}
```

I want the first method to require basic auth only, and the second to require the user to have the right certificate as well to access the method.

The problem is that I'm having trouble using one or the other without having them at the same time. I have tried a few things I read online, right now my WebSecurityConfig class looks like this

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig{

public static class BasicAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authentication)
            throws Exception
    {
        authentication.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }   
}
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class X509SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/user/certiTest").authorizeRequests()

                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()

                .x509()

                    .subjectPrincipalRegex("CN=(.*?)(?:,|$)")

                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService());

        http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
        .maxAgeInSeconds(0)
        .includeSubDomains(true);

    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return (UserDetailsService) username -> {
            if (username.equals("server")) {
                return new User(username, "",
                        AuthorityUtils
                                .commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s not found", username));
            }
        };
    }
}

    }
```

The thing is right now both are setup, so I require both the certificate and the login for it to work. I believe I have the right configuration in the application.yml, I have tried to play with client-auth: want or need, without success.

I'm pretty sure there is a way simpler way to handle this. If someone has a solution, I would be glad.

Answer (score -2):

[Maintain separate class for cofiguration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QApbr.png)

Comment: Please provide some explanation in the answer. Not only links.